# Run Azure Cloud Shell from my Powershell Window

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

Is there a way to run Azure Cloud Shell NOT in a browser?

I would like to use the Azure Cloud Shell commands, but not have to do it in a browser window.

Comment: Is Azure Cli that you are looking for ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview?view=azps-3.1.0) is an interactive, authenticated, **browser-accessible** shell for managing Azure resources. It could provide you with browser-based shell experience so that you can work with it on Bash or Powershell anywhere.

I don't think you can run it not in a browser. However, if you just want to run the Azure cloud shell commands from your Powershell locally. You can look up [Azure PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-3.1.0). You will first [install the Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.1.0) on your Windows machine, then you can start to work with Azure PowerShell commands to manage your Azure resources.